# How to under the query plan of spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What does the `build right` mean of below query plan text?

`BroadcastHashJoin [i_item_sk#2], [ss_item_sk#25], Inner, BuildLeft`

Does that mean the right table is the table get broadcast? 
Also, could I confirm that the table contains the column `ss_item_sk` is the right table from the query plan text?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`buildSide` is the side that going to be broadcasted. In your case `left` relation is broadcasted.

Not always both sides can be broadcasted:

- `inner join` - we can broadcast both sides
- `full outer join` - BHJ is not supported
- `right outer join` - we only can broadcast the `left` side
- `left outer, left semi, left anti` - we only can broadcast the `right` side

> Also, could I confirm that the table contains the column ss_item_sk is
>   the right table from the query plan text?

Yes